# pyaudio-OSError: [Errno -9999] Unanticipated host error

Tags: python, record, pyaudio

I just want to run a simple python audio code:

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import sys

CHUNK = 1024
wf = wave.open("4.wav", 'rb')
# instantiate PyAudio (1)
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
# open stream (2)
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                rate=wf.getframerate(),
                output=True)
```

but I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rec2.py", line 17, in <module>
    output=True)
  File "C:\Users\Surena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 750,  in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Surena\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 441, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
OSError: [Errno -9999] Unanticipated host error
```

I tried another pyaudio record too, the same error came up. I also tried uninstall pyaudio and install it again using pip install pyaudio, but it did not help. I even uninstalled anaconda3 and reinstall it.nothing changed.

what is the problem?

Comment: The method works in my case:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43841316/pyaudio-oserror-errno-9999-unanticipated-host-error/57086198#57086198

Comment: I got the same problem and this is method works in my case:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43841316/pyaudio-oserror-errno-9999-unanticipated-host-error/57086198#57086198

Comment: Shutting off antivirus as proposed in that thread didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and I fix it just by enable/disable the access to the microphone in Setting>Confidentiality>Microphone (on Windows 10)

Comment: On my windows, it's "Setting>Privacy>Microphone".

Answer (score 1):

You need to collect additional information to understand the problem. From [Portaudio docs](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/api_overview.html):

> PortAudio usually tries to translate error conditions into portable
>   PaError error codes. However if an unexpected error is encountered the
>   paUnanticipatedHostError code may be returned. In this case a further
>   mechanism is provided to query for Host API-specific error
>   information. If PortAudio returns paUnanticipatedHostError you can
>   call Pa_GetLastHostErrorInfo() to retrieve a pointer to a
>   PaHostErrorInfo structure that provides more information, including
>   the Host API that encountered the error, a native API error code and
>   error text.

If you have this error on Linux, most likely it is caused by incompatible sample rate you are trying to request from the driver. This value

```
            rate=wf.getframerate()
```

can be changed to 16000, 44100 and 48000 to test which rate is actually supported.

Comment: I am having this issue on Win10 and tried the privacy and antivirus solutions proposed by others. Verified I am using the right input by enumerating sound devices. I'd like to try your method but can you help by explaining a bit more about how to call Pa_GetLastHostErrorInfo() ?  I tried to look for documentation but didn't find how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem so i just give allow permission to microphone from setting and its work
just go to setting --> Privacy --> Microphone  then give the persmission to mic means on the microphone

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows 10 search for *microphone privacy settings*

Answer (score 0):

Okay so if you using jupyter-notebook and you face this challenge. install pyaudio with homebrew(brew install pyaudio) and then restart your kernel.